# Passing parameters to Javascript from jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a javascript function that I need to call on click of the delete button -

JavaScript:

```
function test(var1) {
    alert(var1);
}
```

JSP code (`logs` is an `ArrayList` of length 10):

```
<table>
<%
for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
{
%>
    <tr>
    <td><%out.println(logs[i].getItemName());%></td>
    <td><%out.println(logs[i].getItemDesc()); %></td>
    <td> <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="test(<%logs[i].getItemName();%>);"/></td>
    </tr>

<%
}
%>
</table>
```

This will print the output as -

```
Name1        Description1       Delete_Button

Name2        Description2       Delete_Button

.

.

Name10        Description10     Delete_Button
```

I am not getting how to send the correct itemname value to the JavaScript, when I click on a corresponding row's delete button. Currently I am getting the value as undefined in the JavaScript alert when I click any of the delete buttons.

Comment: Apart from the JavaScript part: Do you really use JSP code like that? Have you ever heard of `<c:foreach/>`? I would avoid `<% %>` in all my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
onclick='test("<%=logs[i].getItemName();%>");'
```